# IOS callback on UIButton click

Tags: ios, objective-c, callback, uibutton, custom-controls

I have a button which is used in many screens of my app. I want to implement a custom button with a custom image and a callback when the button is pressed.

I'm used to java but I don't know how to solve this in iOS. I have read about Category and Subclassing, but I'm still not sure.

Does anyone have an example?. Or what's the best solution for that?. I would really appreciate any help.

What I have done (Thanks @Aris):

.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIButton (MyUIButton)

+ (UIButton *)customButtonWithTarget:(id)target;

@end
```

.m file

```
#import "UIButton+MyUIButton.h"

@implementation UIButton (MyUIButton)

+ (UIButton *)customButtonWithTarget:(id)target{
    UIButton *button_ = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    [button_ setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 44)];
    [button_ setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [button_ addTarget:target
                action:@selector(event_button_click:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return button_;
}

@end
```

In my ViewController:

```
#import "UIButton+MyUIButton.h"

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton customButtonWithTarget:self];
    [self.view addSubview:myButton];

}

-(void)event_button_click
{
    // code here
}
```

I get this error : `'-[ViewController event_button_click:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x78e5df10'`

Comment: in xcode its much easier right click on the button in the interface builder and drag to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclassing a UIButton is the wrong approach to this. What you need is to add a category factory method that creates a button with the properties that you need.
Expanding on JNYJ's answer:

```
+ (UIButton *)customButtonWithTarget:(id)target{
    UIButton *button_ = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button_ setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 44)];
    [button_ setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"File path"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [button_ addTarget:target 
                action:@selector(event_button_click:) 
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return button;
}
```

You should place this method in a UIButton Category that you can create with Xcode and then import the file to all the places that you need to create the button.
After you import the category you can call the method like this:

`[UIButton customButtonWithTarget:target];`

You must ensure thet `target` implements a method named `event_button_click:`.

In a typical scenario the Button's target should be the viewController responsible for the View. If you want the Button to do the same action on all ViewControllers then the ViewControllers should be a subclass of a ViewController that implements the common action.

Another way to achieve this is to set the target to an object that you know will exist throughout the application lifecycle. A candidate could be the `Application Delegate` or some other singleton.

In Response to OP's edit:

The error you are getting this error is because the selector has ":" at the end.
This means that the method should take 1 parameter.
The typical method that responds to a button tap has this signature:

```
- (void)didTapButton:(id)sender
```

Where `sender` is the object that generated the event, in our case the button.

So in your case:

```
-(void)event_button_click:(id)sender
{
    UIButton * myButton = sender
    //custom code
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Aris, the problem is where do I add the delegate

Comment: By delegate you mean what you should use as target?

Comment: Should I make `[UIButton customButtonWithTarget:self];` in my ViewControllers?

Comment: Thanks you very much for your time and help. I made a really stupid mistake..now it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Subclassing is a way to abstract UIButton so that you can use it any places you want with the same functionality.

So, you will subclass from the UIButton. Because UIButton is inherited from UIControl, you are not able to find the method to add selector in UIButton's docs. The method you are going to use  to add selector is in the UIControl's docs. Using the following is to add selector to a button.

> addTarget:action:forControlEvents:

When you want to use it, you just need to initialize like you initialize other objects. Normally, you will use "alloc" and "init". But UIButton has a factory to initialize it.

For multiple usage, you can use make it static so that you don't have to initialize it every time you need it like creating a data manager.

Answer (score 0):

Have look at this codes:

```
UIButton *button_ = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button_ setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 44)];
[button_ setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"File path"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button_ addTarget:self action:@selector(event_button_click:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.view addSubview:button_];




// CALL BACK
-(void)event_button_click:(id)sender{
//Do what event you want when click button (Touch up inside)
}
```

if you have any problem, please tell me, TKS.

Comment: Thanks for your help @JNYJ. The problem is that I would have to repeat your piece of code in all the ViewControllers. That's what I would like to make a custom object

Answer (score 0):

Create custom button class inherits from `UIButton` class and add the customizations you needed for your button there.
Define a `delegate protocol` in your button `class`, with methods to notify the tap events.

And in your class create the button and add as `subview` , implement the `delegate` methods there to get the events from the `button`.

Comment: Thanks @Alex, I think that's exactly what I need. Could you please tell my how to access to the tap events in my button subclass?